# Get String values from hashtable without using loops in Android Studio

Tags: java, android-studio, hashtable

I am struggling to get String values from my Hashtable.

```
public static Hashtable<String, String> table = new Hashtable();

public static HashMap record = new HashMap();

record.put("Key_1","Name" + "Surname" + "Student_Number");
record.put("Key_2","Name" + "Surname" + "Student_Number");
record.put("Key_3","Name" + "Surname" + "Student_Number");

table.putAll(record);
```

This is the same principle I am using in my code. Since I am using GUI in Android Studio I have EditTexts that give us the user input.

Is there a way to ONLY get the surname from the hashtable from lets say Key_1?
But the thing is without using a loop.

We've got an assignment and the specification are that we are not allowed to use any loop in the program.

Comment: Why are you using [`Hashtable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html)? Is your code multi-threaded? Javadoc says: *If a thread-safe implementation is not needed, it is recommended to use `HashMap` in place of `Hashtable`.* It's been saying that since Java 1.2, wayyyy back in 1998.

Comment: You can get a value from the hashtable by doing `String n = table.get("Key_1");`. You don't need a loop anywhere.

Comment: How do you intend to extract only the surname from the combined string `NameSurnameStudent_Number`?

Comment: I intent in using string manipulation to get the surname. The assignment said that we MUST use hashtables. I personally would've used databasing  and 'n webserver to accomplish the LOGIN_SIMULATOR, but the lecturer thinks it isn't a data stucture so now I am using Hashtables.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Appreciate it.

Comment: You should create a Student class with the attributes name, surname and studentNumber, store them in your table and get the surname via a getter.